# Are there any examples of compiling C# code using Mono so that the exe can run with Google's native client support?

Tags: mono, google-nativeclient

I have found a press release that states that Mono now support compilation for native client. It's unclear whether this is only available from the separate github mono fork, or as part of the standard distribution.

I've built the forked mono distribution, but I have been unable to find any examples on how to build a native client executable so that I can run it in Chrome.

Is anyone aware of an example project, or can you provide an example for how to build a Mono application for NaCl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think some of the changes may have been upstreamed, but as of today (11/16/11) there are definitely bugfixes that are still only in the github fork ( https://github.com/elijahtaylor/mono/ ). To build mono for nacl, follow the instructions in the mono/nacl directory ( https://github.com/elijahtaylor/mono/tree/master/nacl ). You want the mono runtime, which will build a mono which can be embedded in your nacl module and can JIT-compile .NET assemblies.
(There is also a mono AOT compiler which runs on linux/mac and generates nacl modules, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work right now, as nobody is using or testing it).

See nacl/test/my.c and mono/mini/fsacheck.c for examples of how to call the mono runtime to JIT code from your nacl module. Inside the browser you'll have to come up with your own way (e.g. pepper and/or nacl-mounts) to get the bytcode into your nacl module.

Comment: There's not been a lot of activity; the x86 changes were taken upstream but not the ARM changes. It should still be possible to build and use the fork but I would expect there to be a few issues to work out. If you're interested you could give it a try and then ask more specific questions here or on native-client-discuss@googlegroups.com

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it's been up-streamed into the Mono repository, but there's a fork that runs on NaCl here : https://github.com/elijahtaylor/mono
Note, use at your own risk!

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/native-client-discuss/hHYJbE-IL2M/0sbbOn0jWpAJ) from March 2012 indicates that Chrome 19 has Native Client support for [Embedded Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono)

> Versions of Mono for Native Client are now available for download in
>   the SDK.  These are compiled with glibc and the libmono comes as a
>   dynamic library.  Only pepper_19 and above has Mono available.
>
> Note that you must keep your pepper_X and naclmono_X bundles in sync
>   (ie, don't update one without updating the other) or you will probably
>   be unable to run the resulting built nexes.  New versions of Mono that
>   match a given SDK should be available within hours of a new SDK build
>   being available.
>
> Only embedded Mono is supported in Native Client currently
>   (http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono).