# How to build Leptonica library under Google pnacl-clang++

Tags: c++, clang++, google-nativeclient

Does anyone know how to build Leptonica library under pnacl-clang++.

I can build the library using clang++ compiler.

```
cd leptonica-1.71
./configure CC="clang" CXX="clang++" --enable-shared
make
```

I don't know how to `configure` pnacl-clang++ to build Leptonica library.

Per Google documentation, This is how every file is compiled separately.

```
e.g.
nacl_sdk/pepper_<version>/toolchain/win_pnacl/bin/pnacl-clang++ \
      hello_world.cc -Inacl_sdk/pepper_<version>/include -c \
      -o hello_world.o -g -O0
```

But, I don't want to run pnacl-clang++ separately on every individual file in the library folder. I must `configure` it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNaCl expects everything to be build as static libraries, not shared, though that's [being worked on](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=3873). For most projects the effort of targeting PNaCl will involve creating a static library build, and setting `CC`/`CXX` to `pnacl-clang`/`pnacl-clang++`.

Open source projects are often already ported on [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList) (and regression-tested), but it looks like leptonica isn't one of these. I suggest looking at other projects' diff to understand what goes into building for PNaCl, and contributing your port of leptonica.

There's a bit more documentation on [building](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/building).

I hope this is useful in building *any* project, not just leptonica :-)

Comment: This is kind of off-topic, but it would be really nice if you could explain the current state of Embedded Mono on Native Client. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922214/are-there-any-examples-of-compiling-c-sharp-code-using-mono-so-that-the-exe-can) has been marked as a favorite question by several people. Thank you.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: the answer on that post is unfortunately still the state of things, Elija's github repo isn't fully upstreamed at the moment.